# Is there any possible way to open file from remote location or network drive in suitable local application?

Tags: php, html

I am working on a problem, but don't know whether it is possible or not. So what I want to do is, I have large files stored on a network or a remote location. I have a page to list all those files e.g. I have 2 files 1) filename1.psd(480 MB) and have a button next to file name "View File", So when I click on filename1.psd it should open that file in locally installed Photoshop 2) filename2.someext (2.03 GB) and have a button next to file name "View File", So when I click on filename2.someext it should open that file in the locally installed application which supports ".someext" filetype automatic

I want to skip downloading a file because of file sizes are too large.

So is there any way to launch the installed application from the system with the file path on a link.

Comment: _"I want to skip downloading a file"_ - If the file isn't downloaded to the client, the client won't be able to read it. Anything you see on internet is _always_ downloaded to the client one way or another, or the client wouldn't be able to display the contents.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Okay

Comment: if the local application doesn't need the whole file ,for example, it needs to read the header, somewhere in the middle, and in the end, then you can map the file as a network drive (possibly with a VPN in the picture). Then the local application will read only the parts that are required. That can work, for ms-access. Another example are text viewers that load only sections on demand. I doubt it will work for photoshop, though.